# R unpack a list of vectors in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

To start: I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895879/unpacking-a-list-in-an-r-dataframe) and no, `tidyr`'s `unnest` doesn't work here. I am doing an `lapply` where the returning function returns a list with named entries (see example `func` at the bottom for clarity):

```
ls <- lapply(x, func)
```

Now if I look at `ls`, it is a list of lists, and in the R studio data viewer it appears as having `Name`, `Type`, and `Value` columns.

Now, if I use

```
df <- bind_rows(ls)
```

I get *exactly* what I want, except I then need to bind the dataframe containing `x` to `df`. This is the problem, because for each `x`, `func` will return a variable number of rows, which means I need to run an equivalent of `bind_rows` after I have already attached `ls` to my dataframe.

An example is as below:

```
func <- function(x){
  res <- list()
  res$name <- 1:x 
  res$val <- 1:x
  return(res)
}

df <- data.frame(nums <- c(1:3), letters <- c("A", "B", "C"))
ls <- lapply(df$nums, func)
```

`bind_rows(ls)` gives:

```
   name   val
  <int> <int>
1     1     1
2     1     1
3     2     2
4     1     1
5     2     2
6     3     3
```

and the desired output is:

```
   name   val  nums letters
  <int> <int> <dbl> <chr>  
1     1     1     1 A      
2     1     1     2 B      
3     2     2     2 B      
4     1     1     3 C      
5     2     2     3 C      
6     3     3     3 C
```

Note that `func` here creates `n` rows given `x = n`. This is not the case for my *actual* function. `func(n)` can produce any positive number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interim, the function I will be using to do this is:

```
merge_and_flatten <- function(x, y){
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    y[[i]][names(x)] <- lapply(x[i, ], rep, times = length(y[[i]][[1]]))
  }
  return(bind_rows(y))
}
```

This is the cleanest solution I could come up with. Here, `x` serves and my `df`, and `y` serves as `ls`. It works by reducing the problem to `bind_rows`: it simply adds elements to `ls` which contain the columns in `x`. I absolutely want a cleaner solution, but this works for anyone who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for something more "canned", but you could write a function that would produce the desired output like this:

```
out <- function(data, varname){
  l <- lapply(data[[varname]], func)
  l <- lapply(1:length(l), function(x)do.call(data.frame, c(l[[x]], zz_obs=x)))
  l <- do.call(rbind, l)
  data$zz_obs <- 1:nrow(data)
  if(!all(data$obs %in% l$obs))warning("Not all rows of data in output\n")
  data <- dplyr::full_join(l, data, by="zz_obs")
  data[,-which(names(data) ==  "zz_obs")]
}

out(df, "nums")
#   name val nums letters
# 1    1   1    1       A
# 2    1   1    2       B
# 3    2   2    2       B
# 4    1   1    3       C
# 5    2   2    3       C
# 6    3   3    3       C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mapply` which is similar to `lapply`, but allows multiple vectors or lists to be passed to iterate over their values:

```r
library(dplyr)
func <- function(x, y){
  res <- list()
  res$name <- 1:x 
  res$val <- 1:x
  res$let <- rep(y, x)
  return(res)
}
df <- data.frame(nums <- c(1:3), letters <- c("A", "B", "C"))

ls <- mapply(
  func, 
  x = df$nums, 
  y =df$letters, 
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE
)
bind_rows(ls)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
#   name   val let  
#  <int> <int> <chr>
# 1     1     1 A    
# 2     1     1 B    
# 3     2     2 B    
# 4     1     1 C    
# 5     2     2 C    
# 6     3     3 C
```

Comment: This is a clever solution, but it requires that I edit `func` or wrap `func` in another function (which I have to in this case because I didn't write `func`), which makes it less-than-reusable.

Comment: wrapper is not a bad option, if you need it. you can also run lapply twice and cbind the outputs